# How to get host's udev events from a Docker container?

Tags: docker, events, udev

In a Docker container, I am looking for a way to get the udev events on the host.
Using `udevadm monitor`, it sends back host's kernel events only in a container.

The question is whether there is a way to detect host's udev events or forward host's event to containers?

Answer (score 12):

This is how I made my container receive host events by udev:

```
docker run --net=host -v /run/udev/control:/run/udev/control
```

--net=host allows container and host operate through PF_NETLINK sockets, which are used by udev monitor to receive kernel events (found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24319662/from-inside-of-a-docker-container-how-do-i-connect-to-the-localhost-of-the-mach))

/run/udev/control is a file, which udev monitor uses to check if udevd is already running. If it doesn't exist, monitoring is disabled.

Comment: yes, this is a method to make it but it is not an ideal one since host mode is not secure.

Answer (score 1):

Just like above answer pointed out: we could enable `--net=host`, but `host network` is not suggested because of multiple known reasons.

In fact this issue happens just because it need `NETLINK` to communicate between kernel & user space, but if not use `host network`, host & container will in different `netns`, so enable `udev` in container could make them in same netns which then no need to use `host network`.

When we ran into this issue, we did next:

```
# apt-get install udev

# vim /etc/init.d/udev to comment some special settings:

    1) Comments next:
    #if [ ! -e "/run/udev/" ]; then
    #    warn_if_interactive
    #fi

    2) Comments next:
    #if ! ps --no-headers --format args ax | egrep -q '^\['; then
    #    log_warning_msg "udev does not support containers, not started"
    #    exit 0
    #fi

# root@e751e437a8ba:~# service udev start
  [ ok ] Starting hotplug events dispatcher: systemd-udevd.
  [ ok ] Synthesizing the initial hotplug events (subsystems)...done.
  [ ok ] Synthesizing the initial hotplug events (devices)...done.
  [ ok ] Waiting for /dev to be fully populated...done.
```

Comment: I can't find section 2) in my host system's `/etc/init.d/udev`. Do I have to do anything inside the container except `service udev start`?

Comment: The change is for `/etc/init.d/udev` in container, it's a separate udev system against hosts', so every operation should be operated in container.